# Sails autoCreatedAt and autoUpdatedAt inserting datetime 5 hours forward form my current timezone

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, timezone, sails.js

Actually I'm working with `SailsJS v0.11.3` and `MongoDB v3.2.1` with `sails-mongo` adapter.

And I am using sails autoCreatedAt and autoUpdatedAd to store timestamps for tracking documents in the different tables.

I have realised that the records are stored with ***+6 hours*** from now in my local timezone which is ***Mexico City***.

i.e.

```
Actual date = 2016-02-11T13:24:23 ==> Stored value = 2016-02-11T19:24:23
```

I have checked the timezone in my linux os and it is set up correctly.

I can't find where is the problem or how to fix it.

Can anybody help me out with that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around the problem and asking some question in [balderdash/sails official](https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails) channel in [Gitter](https://gitter.im), I found the next:

It is very important to always use UTC time. Because that's the standard to store datetimes to DBs.

Storing those to your server timezone will just get you into trouble for different reasons as explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).

- If someone changes your server timezone for some reason you're fucked up!

It is recommended to store them in UTC time and if you need to convert those to your local timezone (or something else) just use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to do that.

You will get consistency in the data because at **anytime you modify** those attributes in the client side they will be **sobered in UTC** and you can easily **get any timezone** from that values, it doesn't matter which timezone you want to get, you can using the UTC values stored in MongoDB.

```
var moment = require('moment');

var date = moment(updatedAt).locale('es').tz('America/Mexico_City').format();
```

You will get the value in the right timezone you want!

```
Feb 10 2016 12:34:01 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

As you can see it shows `CST` time which is the one for Mexico City instead of `UTC` time.

I really recommend to do this! Or at least, it is what I considere the best choice.

I hope it could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDB stores times in UTC by default](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/model-time-data/#overview). Mexico City seems to be on Central Time Zone which is UTC-06:00, thus the six hour difference.

You should be able to see this from MongoDB shell as well:

```
> db.testDate.insert({date: new Date()});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.testDate.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56bb88cbe9ef8429d2c1d6d8"),
        "date" : ISODate("2016-02-10T19:00:27.459Z")
}
```

where the `Z` at the end of the date indicates UTC. It was 21:00 local time when I inserted the date but it shows 19:00 because I'm on UTC+02:00.

Comment: Alright I got it but how to fix that? I mean, every time I fetch data from Mongo return result to the clients in JSON but with the specific timezone?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Sails.js, but one option could be to add [custom `toJSON`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json) that converts the timezone using [Moment](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Comment: Yes I have tested that but I found some disadvantages using a specific local timezone, it is better to store them in `UTC` in `MongoDB` and then just convert them in the client side using `MomentJS` as I expose in my own answer!

Comment: Well yes, obviously better to do in the browser since someday maybe not all your users are in Mexico City. You were asking about fixing the timezone in JSON though. Good you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap.js I always add:

```
process.env['TZ'] = '0';
```

That seems to work with storing everything UTC.